# Video encoding fail from MediaCodec

Tags: android, video-encoding, android-mediacodec

I made video encoding API for yuv frames using MediaCodec.
But it does not work due to unknown error.
My code is following.

```
mediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("video/avc");
MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 1280, 720);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 25);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 4000000);      
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 5);
mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
mediaCodec.start();

ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = mediaCodec.getInputBuffers();
ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = mediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();
int inputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(0);
if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) {
    ByteBuffer inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
    inputBuffer.clear();
    inputBuffer.put(bArData1); // bArData1 : yuv420sp raw data
    mediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, framesize, 0, 0);
}

MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
int outputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 100000);
```

--> **always outputBufferIndex = "-2"**

I don't know what makes this problem.

I checked input data(bArData1) is normal yuv420sp frame.

Could you give me some guide to use it?

Comment: -2 is `INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED`, which is normal after dequeueOutputBuffer().  You may want to check the examples on http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ or in https://github.com/google/grafika.

Comment: Thanks~. Now It works. In case of INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED, It need to dequeueOutputBuffer one more.